# Remove duplicate values from HashMap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, duplicates

I have a map with duplicate values:

```
("A", "1");
("B", "2");
("C", "2");
("D", "3");
("E", "3");
```

I would like to the map to have

```
("A", "1");
("B", "2");
("D", "3");
```

Do you know how to get rid of the duplicate values?

At present, I get 'java.util.ConcurrentModificationException' error.

Thank you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("A", "1");
    map.put("B", "2");
    map.put("C", "2");
    map.put("D", "3");
    map.put("E", "3");

    Set<String> keys = map.keySet(); // The set of keys in the map.

    Iterator<String> keyIter = keys.iterator();

    while (keyIter.hasNext()) {
        String key = keyIter.next();
        String value = map.get(key);

        System.out.println(key + "\t" + value);

        String nextValue = map.get(key);

        if (value.equals(nextValue)) {
            map.remove(key);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Comment: Why do you keep `B` and leave out `C`? Remember, `HashMap` doesn't maintain the order of elements inserted.

Comment: Can you tell the exact requirement? Looks like you want unique values. HashMap can give you unique keys. Will inverting the key and value be enough for you?

Comment: @RohitJain +1 That's the question !

Answer (score 9):

make a reverse HashMap!

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
Set<String> keys = map.keySet(); // The set of keys in the map.

Iterator<String> keyIter = keys.iterator();

while (keyIter.hasNext()) {
    String key = keyIter.next();
    String value = map.get(key);
    map.put(value, key);
}
```

now that you have the hashMap you need reverse it or print it.

in anyway **do not** delete while iterating hashMap. save the values in a list and delete them in an outer loop

Comment: It will still be random which element will be kept (because the order of a `HashMap` is undefined), but if that's no issue, this works fine.

Comment: @Heuster i agree, but he didn't said it's an issue

Comment: @NoIdeaForName why there is map.add() and not map.put()

Comment: @bot13 can't say i remember if there was a reason for this, it was 6 years back. works with `put` as well.

Comment: It is only possible if both key and value are of same type

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that you use **Java 8**, it could be done using the [`Stream API`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) with a `Set<String>` that will store the existing values:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("A", "1");
...
System.out.printf("Before: %s%n", map);

// Set in which we keep the existing values
Set<String> existing = new HashSet<>();
map = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(entry -> existing.add(entry.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
System.out.printf("After: %s%n", map);
```

**Output:**

```
Before: {A=1, B=2, C=2, D=3, E=3}
After: {A=1, B=2, D=3}
```

**NB:** Strictly speaking a predicate of a filter is not supposed to be **stateful**, it should be **stateless** as mentioned into the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) in order to ensure that the result remain **deterministic** and **correct** even if we use a parallel stream. However here, I assume that you don't intend to use a parallel stream such that this approach remains valid.

Comment: Strictly speaking streams shouldn't really be used with a side-effecting filter.

Comment: @GraemeMoss that's right, I added a comment to avoid misuse/misunderstanding

Comment: You can replace .filter() by .distinct()

Answer (score 5):

```
    Map<String,Object> mapValues = new HashMap<String,Object>(5);
    mapValues.put("1", "TJ");
    mapValues.put("2", "Arun");
    mapValues.put("3", "TJ");
    mapValues.put("4", "Venkat");
    mapValues.put("5", "Arun");

    Collection<Object> list = mapValues.values();
    for(Iterator<Object> itr = list.iterator(); itr.hasNext();)
    {
        if(Collections.frequency(list, itr.next())>1)
        {
            itr.remove();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Some explanation or links for further details would be helpful. Especially if asked why some Exception thrown there is need.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using Java 8. The concept of stream is required. The pseudocode,
is stream().filter().collect().
If the Initial Map : {A=1, B=2, C=2, D=3, E=3}. Then the required answer after removing the duplicates is   {A=1, B=2, D=3} .

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class RemoveDuplicates1 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Initial Map : {A=1, B=2, C=2, D=3, E=3}
        //After =>  {A=1, B=2, D=3} 

      Map<String , String > map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("A", "1");
        map.put("B", "2");
        map.put("C", "2");
        map.put("D", "3");
        map.put("E", "3");

        System.out.printf("before :   " +map );
        System.out.println("\n");

        Set<String> set = new  HashSet<>();

        map = map.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> set.add(entry.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry :: getKey ,  Map.Entry :: getValue));
        System.out.printf("after => " + map);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ConcurrentModificationException` happening,because you are removing from `map`

```
  if (value.equals(nextValue)) {
            map.remove(key);
        }
```

You have to remove from `iterator`

```
if (value.equals(nextValue)) {
            keyIter.remove(key);
        }
```

Coming to the duplicate entry issue,Its pretty simple :[Find duplicate values in Java Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895192/find-duplicate-values-in-java-map)

Comment: Well, if you see his code clearly, this won't really solve his problem.

Comment: This code is wrong , it won't compile and neither does it solves the problem .

Comment: iterator ,`Iterator<String> keyIter = keys.iterator();`

Comment: And what is [keyIter.remove(key)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()) ?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot :That avoids the exception `The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.`

Comment: Please go through the syntax first and then the documentation .

Comment: Please feel free to edit, If you found some mistake,Or please convey the exact reason why I it won't compile,It's working fine In my IDE.

Answer (score 1):

If this is yours frequent requirement then `DualHashBidiMap` calss of  apache's [commons.collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections//javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/BidiMap.html)  will help you more instead of using `HashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("A", "1");
    map.put("B", "2");
    map.put("C", "2");
    map.put("D", "3");
    map.put("E", "3");
    System.out.println("Initial Map : " + map);
    for (String s : new ConcurrentHashMap<>(map).keySet()) {
        String value = map.get(s);
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> ss : new ConcurrentHashMap<>(map)
                .entrySet()) {
            if (s != ss.getKey() && value == ss.getValue()) {
                map.remove(ss.getKey());
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Final Map : " + map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done by putting your hashmap into arraylist.
This arraylist is of hashmap type.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<>();
map.put("1", "1");
        mArrayList.add(map);
        map=new HashMap<>();
        map.put("1", "1"); 
        mArrayList.add(map);
        map=new HashMap<>();
        map.put("1", "2");
        mArrayList.add(map);
        map=new HashMap<>();
        map.put("1", "3");
        mArrayList.add(map);
        map=new HashMap<>();
        map.put("1", "2");
        mArrayList.add(map);

for(int i=0;i<mArrayList.size();i++)
        {
            temp=mArrayList.get(i).get("1");
            for(int k=i+1;k<mArrayList.size();k++)
            {
                if(temp.equals(mArrayList.get(k).get("1")))
                {
                    mArrayList.remove(k); 
                } 
            }

        }
```

Now print your arraylist...all the duplicate values from the hashmap easily removed...This is the easiest way to remove duplicacy

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful to remove duplicate values from map.

```
    Map<String, String> myMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    myMap.put("1", "One");
    myMap.put("2", "Two");
    myMap.put("3", "One");
    myMap.put("4", "Three");
    myMap.put("5", "Two");
    myMap.put("6", "Three");

    Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>();

    for (Iterator itr = myMap.entrySet().iterator(); itr.hasNext();)
    {
        Map.Entry<String, String> entrySet = (Map.Entry) itr.next();

        String value = entrySet.getValue();

        if (!mySet.add(value))
        {
            itr.remove();               
        }
    }
```

System.out.println("mymap :" + mymap);

Output:

mymap :{1=One, 2=Two, 4=Three}

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking just to remove the concurrentModification exception, then just replace your HashMap with ConcurrentHashMap.

To know more about ConcurrentHashMap look [here](https://www.journaldev.com/378/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without mutating the original map:

```java
public static <K,V> Map<K,V> getDistinctValues(Map<K,V> map) {
    Set<V> values = new HashSet<>();

    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> values.add(entry.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Map.Entry::getValue
            ));
}
```