# Java - how to remove duplicating entries from HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, duplicates

I have a `HashMap` in Java:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> meh = new HashMap<String, Integer>();`

meh.put("one", 1);
meh.put("one", 1);
meh.put("one", 1);
meh.put("two", 1);
meh.put("two", 2);
meh.put("three", 3);
```

What I need is to remove duplicating entries ("one", 1) [when both key and value duplicate]. I searched and found only 'how to remove duplicating keys/values'. Can anyone help?

Comment: It is already done... you cannot have more than one entry with the same key...

Comment: are you sure you can have duplicate keys? Check the java docs first...

Comment: Maps will not let you have entry with same key more than once. Like in real world, point on map can describe only one location, so each time you use `put(key, value)` with same key you are only updating existing value. Only way I can think of for map to store more than one entries with same key is when instance of key is of a type which has incorrectly overridden hashcode and equals methods, which is impossible for keys of type String.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812454/remove-duplicate-values-from-hashmap-in-java

Comment: @Ascalonian: That's not a duplicate, that question has no duplicate keys.

Comment: Yes, I do have duplicaing entries, because I put values into HashMap from a database.

Comment: `Map`s cannot contain duplicate keys, regardless of the associated value.  That's one of their a central aspects.

Comment: @user3605970 the point is that a Hashmap cannot have duplicate keys! it may have duplicate values with  different keys, but not duplicate keys.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to do that, HashMap takes care of that automatically. What happens when you execute that code is essentially as follows:

```
meh.put("one", 1);
```

this makes the map {"one" -> 1}

```
meh.put("one", 1);
```

this replaces the assignment by itself, making the map {"one" -> 1}

```
meh.put("one", 1);
```

this replaces the assignment by itself, making the map {"one" -> 1}

```
meh.put("two", 1);
```

this adds the requested linking, making the map {"one" -> 1, "two" -> 1}

```
meh.put("two", 2);
```

this replaces the assignment for "two", making the map {"one" -> 1, "two" -> 2}

```
meh.put("three", 3);
```

this adds the new element, making the total mapping  {"one" -> 1, "two" -> 2, "three" -> 3} with no duplicates involved.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove duplicates from a `HashMap` because there are no duplicates in a `HashMap` in the first place. The second (or third, or whatever) time you call `put` with a key that already exists in the map, it will simply override the value with a new one, regardless of whether it's a duplicate or not of the pre-existing one.

In the code snippet you provided, the map will only have three values.

Answer (score 2):

From what you describe, `Map<String, Integer>` is not the structure adapted to your needs: you do not seem to assiciate the value `2` to `"two"` but you are actually storing pairs of elements.

A better data structure might be to use a `Set` of `MyPair` where `MyPair` is:

```
public class MyPair {
    private String first;
    private int second;
    // + constructor, getters + setters, hashcode + equals
}
```

And then you can use that `MyPair` object in a `HashSet`:

```
Set<MyPair> myPairs = new HashSet();
myPairs.add(new MyPair("one", 1));
myPairs.add(new MyPair("one", 2));
myPairs.add(new MyPair("two", 2));    
myPairs.add(new MyPair("two", 2));
myPairs.remove(new MyPair("one", 2)); // remove MyPair("one", 2) only
```

Comment: Beat me by four seconds, plus I like your explicit observation that OP is really just storing pairs of elements.  I'm leaving mine because OP's use of a hashmap suggests there might be a need to extract all the unique values mapped to by a key.

Answer (score 1):

Your real question isn't how to remove duplicates.

**It's how to preserve the unique values with duplicate keys.**

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8229534/152578 by Jon Skeet for details, but basically you're looking for a multimap.

You'll have to check for the value on insertion.

Another choice would be to unite the key and value (method depending on your symbol space), and store them in a set.