# How to remove duplicate key from a Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, duplicates

I have a list of list. There is a list within a list.
`[[-1, 0, 1], [-1, 2, -1], [0, 1, -1]]`, name of this list say result. result list contain duplicate elements as a list. `[-1,0,1]` and `[0,1,-1]` they are same. I want to make a list which does not contain duplicates. So list result become `[[-1,0,1],[-1,2,-1]]` or `[[-1,2,-1],[0,1,-1]]` .

I read that Hashmap can not store duplicate keys but allow duplicate values. So to remove duplicates I was trying Hashmap.

But after writing the code it run well there is no error.

```
HashMap<List<Integer>,Integer> final_sol=new HashMap<>();
for(int k1=0;k1<result.size();k1++){
       final_sol.put(result.get(k1),k1);
    }
    System.out.println(final_sol);
```

Output:

```
{[-1, 2, -1]=1, [0, 1, -1]=2, [-1, 0, 1]=0}
```

After writing this code blocks I thought my duplicate keys cannot shown only unique keys displayed.

Then how could I make this list unique using Hash map?[Fail to understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243740/java-how-to-remove-duplicating-entries-from-hashmap)

When I was using tree map it doesn't compile and gave som eerror.

Comment: `[-1,0,1]` and `[0,1,-1]` are **not** the same. `[-1,0,1]` and `[-1,0,1]' are the same. `[0,1,-1]` and `[0,1,-1]` are the same. Lists are *ordered*, so the value order is important when comparing lists. --- If you want to consider `[-1,1,0]` and `[0,1,-1]` the same, *sort* them first, so they both become `[-1,0,1]`, *then* add to `HashMap`.

Comment: Besides it also depends on what you are using as a concrete class for List. We cannot know from your given code as we can only see the List interface :) But I assume you use ArrayList so I totally agree with @Andreas.

Comment: @YavuzTas Even if original lists are not `ArrayList`, you can always copy to `ArrayList` before sorting, leaving the original lists unmodified.

Comment: @Andreas Of course copying can be a workaround in these situations so I agree once more

Comment: Is [0, 1, 1] the same as [0, 0, 1] or [0, 1]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
List<List<Integer>> result = Arrays.asList(
      Arrays.asList(-1, 0, 1),
      Arrays.asList(-1, 2, -1),
      Arrays.asList(0, 1, -1)
);
HashMap<Set<Integer>, List<Integer>> final_sol = new HashMap<>();

for (List<Integer> list : result) {
  final_sol.put(new HashSet<>(list), list);
}

System.out.println(final_sol.values());
```

You think, that `[-1,0,1]` and `[0,1,-1]` they are same, but this does not hold for lists, because order of elements matters. You need sets for this understanding of equals.

But even then it may not be what you expected, when `[0,0,1]` and `[0,1,1]` are same. In this case you must transform each list to a Map which gives you the count of the same `Integer` in the original list.

Comment: It is working. Now if I save those values in a list of list how could I save it. Function return type `public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) `. I should find out the answer in this format.

Comment: The result of `final_sol.values()` is of type `Collection<List<Integer>>`. You can convert it to a list like this: `List<List<Integer>> resList = new ArrayList<>(final_sol.values());`.

Answer (score 10):

It is true that Maps do not retain duplicate keys and Sets do not retain duplicate elements, but you need to understand that "duplicate" is defined in terms of keys / elements `equals()` methods, and that hash-based collections depend on their keys / elements having `hashCode()` methods that are consistent with their `equals()` methods.

Now you say

> `[-1,0,1]` and `[0,1,-1]` they are same.

, but no, they are *not* the same as far as `List`s' definition of equality goes.  The order of list elements is significant, and Lists are required to implement `equals()` in a manner that reflects that.  That's why both those lists may appear as keys in the same `Map`, and both may appear as elements in the same `Set`.

> Then how could I make this list unique using Hash map?

Apparently order is *not* significant for your purposes, so `List`s aren't really the right model for you to work with.  If you do not need to accommodate duplicate elements, then you should consider using Sets instead.  The standard library provides several implementations, of which `HashSet` would probably be the most suited to your situation as I understand it.  If you *do* need to accommodate duplicate elements, then you're looking for a multiset.  The standard library does not provide an implementation, but there are several available from third parties.

> When I was using tree map it doesn't compile and gave some error.

Well yes, it would, unless you provided it with a `Comparator` by which to determine the relative order of your elements.  `TreeMap` recognizes duplicates as keys that compare equal according to their natural or Comparator-specified order.

Overall, it sounds like instead of a list of lists, you want a set of sets or a set of multisets.  I don't see why you would want to bring maps into it.

Comment: Instead of using `Set` or `Multiset`, you could also just sort the `List` elements, to get a consistent ordering, so e.g. `[-1,1,0]` and `[0,1,-1]` would become the same, i.e. `[-1,0,1]`. Since ordering doesn't matter, there should be no need to retain the original ordering anyway.

Comment: Agreed, @Andreas.  If one wants to go that route, however, then one has to be careful to do the extra work needed to ensure that the inner lists are sorted.  That needs to be weighed against the advantages, if any, of retaining List form.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can do this on-line with a `Set<Set<Integer>>`. That gives you `[[-1, 0, 1], [-1, 2]]`; homomorphic to `[[-1, 0, 1], [-1, 2, -1]]`, but not your desired result. The following is for a set of vectors of three integers that compare equal with any permutation, which is consistent with your examples. Per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--), overriding `equals` requires an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), and necessarily, `hashCode`, such that `a == b -> hashCode(a) == hashCode(b)`.

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.Integer;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

class Java {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Set<Three> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        set.add(new Three(-1, 0, 1));
        set.add(new Three(-1, 2, -1));
        set.add(new Three(0, 1, -1));
        System.out.printf("%s.\n", set);
    }

}

final class Three {
    private int a, b, c;
    public Three(final int a, final int b, final int c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() { return a + b + c; }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(this == o) return true;
        if(!(o instanceof Three)) return false;
        Three t = (Three)o;
        /* Brute force 3! = 6. */
        return a == t.a && b == t.b && c == t.c
            || a == t.a && b == t.c && c == t.b
            || a == t.b && b == t.a && c == t.c
            || a == t.b && b == t.c && c == t.a
            || a == t.c && b == t.a && c == t.b
            || a == t.c && b == t.b && c == t.a;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "["+a+","+b+","+c+"]";
    }
}
```

This produces,

```
[[-1,0,1], [-1,2,-1]].
```

Edit: The following is a replacement for the above code for a set of vectors of three integers that compare equal when put in a set, which is also consistent with your examples.

```
    /** Hashcode is the sum of the unique numbers. */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int h = a;
        if(a != b) h += b;
        if(c != a && c != b) h += c;
        return h;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(this == o) return true;
        if(!(o instanceof Three)) return false;
        Three t = (Three)o;
        /* t \in this && this \in t. */
        return (a == t.a || a == t.b || a == t.c)
            && (b == t.a || b == t.b || b == t.c)
            && (c == t.a || c == t.b || c == t.c)
            && (t.a == a || t.a == b || t.a == c)
            && (t.b == a || t.b == b || t.b == c)
            && (t.c == a || t.c == b || t.c == c);
    }
```