# How to delete duplicates values from HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I need to delete all duplicates from my HashMap but those duplicates are the                  lists inside the HashMap.

For example:

```
      HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Intteger>> myList = new HashMap<>();

      myList.put(0, list0);
      myList.put(1, list1);
      myList.put(2, list2);
      myList.put(3, list3);
      myList.put(4, list4);
```

Now when I display all elements of the HashMap I've got:

```
  0 [1,3]
   1 [0,3]
   2 [1,3]
   3 [1,4]
   4 [2,4]
```

How can I remove array's duplicate?
As you can see in this case elements with key 0 and 2
have the same values so I want to remove the duplicate.
`

Comment: Why my question is closed? This case describe totally different situation than in the question you have attached here. I want to delete duplicates of ArrayList inside HashMap and unfortunately your question doesn't help me in this situation.

Comment: Actually the duplicate cited will solve your issue. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26135521/1552534). Starting with the solution and not the data either change the Collection type from `Object` to `List<Integer>` or from `Object` to `? extends Object`. It will delete the duplicate values from your map.   But remember that the keys are unordered so the remaining value may be a different key than what you want.

Comment: Correction.  ...the remaining value may be *`associated with`* a different key than what you want.