# how to remove duplicate value from hash map

Tags: java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class MyClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HashMap<Integer, String> hm = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        hm.put(1, "Anil");
        hm.put(2, "Deven");
        hm.put(3, "sanjay");
        hm.put(4, "sanjay");
        hm.put(5, "Raj");
        hm.put(6, "sanjay");

        Set<Integer> keys = hm.keySet();

    }

}
```

This my code i want to remove all duplicate value from hash-map and want print on console please tell me how i will do this .

Comment: How do you decide which key-pair needs to be kept and which needs to be removed as a duplicate?

Comment: see i Just go Through Goodle in Arraylist i am able to remove duplicate  but i just want to learn how i will remove from hasmap ?

Comment: You can find a solution here: [Find duplicate values in Java Map?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895192/find-duplicate-values-in-java-map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HashMap is `hm`. Put the values of `hm` in another HashMap `hm2` in which the values of `hm` are the keys of `hm2`, and the values of `hm2` can be anything (e.g. the object Boolean.TRUE).

Then loop through that second HashMap `hm2` and print out its keys.

Instead of `HashMap` you can also use `HashSet` for `hm2` (this is even better as you would not need the Boolean.TRUE part).

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<Integer, String> hm = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        hm.put(1, "Anil");
        hm.put(2, "Deven");
        hm.put(3, "sanjay");
        hm.put(4, "sanjay");
        hm.put(5, "Raj");
        hm.put(6, "sanjay");

        HashSet<String> hm2 = new HashSet<String>();
        hm2.addAll(hm.values());

        for (String str : hm2){
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to keep the mapping along with the key if you want duplicate values to be eliminated, as unique keys associated with duplicate values will also be dropped off from the map.

If you just need a list of unique values from the map try this:

Try this:

```
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(hm.values());
    System.out.println(set);
```

> Output: [Anil, Deven, Raj, sanjay]

Answer (score 2):

Invert the map twice

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class UniqueMapValues
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<Integer, String> hm = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        hm.put(1, "Anil");
        hm.put(2, "Deven");
        hm.put(3, "sanjay");
        hm.put(4, "sanjay");
        hm.put(5, "Raj");
        hm.put(6, "sanjay");

        hm = invert(invert(hm));

        System.out.println(hm);
    }

    private static <K, V> Map<V, K> invert(Map<K, V> map)
    {
        Map<V, K> result = new HashMap<V, K>();
        for (Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet())
        {
            result.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```