# how to remove duplicate entries when displayed in listview

Tags: android

i have textfile and i manage to display it in listview , my problem is that i want to remove the duplicate entries in column Category, Code,Description when displayed in listview. Thank you for helping! [//here is my textfile with duplicate entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD1DV.png)

//here is my code in displaying

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllProducts() {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> proList;
        proList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Countsheet";
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put("Category", cursor.getString(1));
                map.put("Code", cursor.getString(2));
                map.put("Description", cursor.getString(3));
                map.put("Unit", cursor.getString(4));
                map.put("Quantity", cursor.getString(5));
                proList.add(map);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return proList;
    }
```

Comment: You should basically look into how to remove duplicates from a HashMap. Here is a good start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21625772/how-to-remove-duplicate-value-from-hash-map

Comment: Will a SELECT DISTINCT not solve the requirement?

Comment: @RobE - when i used distinct my app keeps on crashing dont know why

Comment: Without error? What does the attempt and the resulting error look like?

Comment: @Calypso thanks ill try this and inform you as soon as possilbe thank you

Comment: @RobE - i forgot , i need to retain the unit i just need to remove duplicate entries in column category , code, description IM SORRY  I FORGOT TO SPECIFY:(

Comment: @Calypso - i forgot , i need to retain the unit i just need to remove duplicate entries in column category , code, description IM SORRY  I FORGOT TO SPECIFY:(

Comment: If you want to aggregate the units per category and have only one row per category then a GROUP BY clause would help.

Comment: @RobE - ok sir ill try that THANKS!